# How do i count number of referals using aggregation in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

this is the schema :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54f8d7ad92ccf803008a0e4f"),
"personal" : {
    "name" : "test",
    "placa" : "BBB222"
},
"recruiter" : {
    "user_id" : "541cba6fe4b0288d56081fe2",
    "date" : 1425594285410,
    "name" : "Mario Hart",
    "rol" : "greeter",
    "channel" : "referido",
    "referred" : "VERA"
},
```

I want to create a list of names counting the number of referals that each one has. I am trying with the following way, but its not working at all.This is the code that i've written.

```
db.drivers.aggregate( {
$group: { _
    id:{"$personal.name",
     "$recruiter.referred"    
     },
        total_recommendations:{ $sum:1}  } 
     }   ])
```

This is not working , i cant make this code works . 
The server that i am running is on the version 2.6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. `$` prefixes are for variable references to fields or otherwise reserved for "operators" when used in the "key" part of "key/value" notation. It also never fails to surprise the number of people who use a "compound key" notation in a grouping `_id` when they have only one field:

```js
db.drivers.aggregate([
    { "$group": { _
        "_id": "$recruiter.referred"    
        "total_recommendations":{ "$sum": 1 }
    }} 
])
```

Comment: $personal.name wasn't doing anything there right ? 
I want to know if you know where can i code this querys with sintax highlights? 
Its because im using the linux shell but i am learning and i cant code a clean code.
Thanks for your time and answer :D

Comment: @Giuseppe if you use valid JSON notation as I do [ because I like to share : ) ] then you can always use a JSON linter. But AFAIK there is nothing that will point out illegal operator usage other than running the query.

Comment: i see , i will download the plugin for sublime then , i totally forgot that this was json notation. Yep , im always sharing my code too . And one last question , i promise! . If i d want to order this by total_recomendations i added this to my query, but it's not ordering . Do you know what is wrong with my "logic" --- 
{$sort:{total_recomendations:1}}?